# Why table() function is giving me long data instead of wide?

Tags: r, contingency

I'm having trouble getting my data set to work with the `table()` function. My data originally looks something like this:

| Student_Ethnicity | Pre_DAS Ethnicity |
| --- | --- |
| White | Black |
| White | White |
| Asian | Black |
| Black | White |
| White | Black |

But, I want it to tabulate like this:

| Student_Ethnicity | White | Black | Asian |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| White | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Black | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Asian | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I previously ran this code:

```
PreDASEthnicityPredictor <- table(Predict_DAS$Student_Ethnicity, Predict_DAS$PreDAS_Ethnicity)
```

But, when the data tabulated it looked like this:

| Student_Ethnicity | Pre_DAS Ethnicity | Frq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| White | White | 1 |
| White | Black | 2 |
| White | Asian | 0 |
| Black | White | 1 |
| Black | Black | 0 |
| Black | Asian | 0 |
| Asian | White | 0 |
| Asian | Black | 1 |
| Asian | Asian | 0 |

Is there a specific reason this could be happening and how can I make this tabulate correctly? It is important to get this table format for a chi-squared analysis I would like to do on this later.

Here is the actual dataset I am working with:

```
structure(list(Predict_DAS.Student_Ethnicity = c("White/Caucasian", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Other", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Multiple", "White/Caucasian", 
"White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", 
"White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", "Hispanic/Latinx", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "Other", "Other", 
"Hispanic/Latinx", "Hispanic/Latinx", "Other", "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander", 
"Black/African American", "Black/African American", "Hispanic/Latinx", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"Hispanic/Latinx", "Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Other", "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "Other", "Hispanic/Latinx", 
"No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "American Indian or Alaskan Native", 
"Hispanic/Latinx", "White/Caucasian", "Hispanic/Latinx", "Black/African American", 
"American Indian or Alaskan Native", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"Multiple", "White/Caucasian", "American Indian or Alaskan Native", 
"No Selection", "Asian", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander", "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander", 
"Hispanic/Latinx", "American Indian or Alaskan Native", "No Selection", 
"Asian", "Black/African American", "Black/African American", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "American Indian or Alaskan Native", 
"Black/African American", "Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", 
"Black/African American", "Black/African American", "Multiple", 
"White/Caucasian", "Hispanic/Latinx", "White/Caucasian", "Asian", 
"Multiple", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"Multiple", "Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"Black/African American", "Other", "Black/African American", 
"Multiple", "Black/African American", "Hispanic/Latinx", "White/Caucasian", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"Black/African American", "Hispanic/Latinx", "Multiple", "Black/African American", 
"Black/African American", "Asian", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "Other", "Multiple", "Multiple", "Multiple", 
"No Selection", "Asian", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "Other", "White/Caucasian", "American Indian or Alaskan Native", 
"White/Caucasian", "Hispanic/Latinx", "Multiple", "Hispanic/Latinx"
), Predict_DAS.PreDAS_Ethnicity = c("White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"Asian", "White/Caucasian", "Other", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "No Selection", "Hispanic/Latinx", 
"Black/African American", "No Selection", "Asian", "Other", "No Selection", 
"No Selection", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "No Selection", 
"No Selection", "Hispanic/Latinx", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "Black/African American", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Hispanic/Latinx", "No Selection", 
"Hispanic/Latinx", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "Asian", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "Hispanic/Latinx", 
"Other", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", "No Selection", 
"White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "Black/African American", 
"No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "Asian", "Multiple", "White/Caucasian", 
"White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "No Selection", "No Selection", 
"Black/African American", "No Selection", "No Selection", "No Selection", 
"White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", "Other", "Black/African American", 
"No Selection", "Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "Black/African American", "No Selection", "No Selection", 
"No Selection", "Black/African American", "Multiple", "Black/African American", 
"Hispanic/Latinx", "Black/African American", "Asian", "Multiple", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "Asian", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"No Selection", "Black/African American", "Black/African American", 
"Black/African American", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "No Selection", 
"Black/African American", "No Selection", "Other", "No Selection", 
"No Selection", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "Other", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "No Selection", 
"White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", "Black/African American", 
"Black/African American", "Other", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", 
"Black/African American", "No Selection", "No Selection")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-140L))
```

Comment: Can you make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  The output you're getting looks what you get when you convert a table into a data frame.  e.g. compare `table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$carb)` to `data.frame(table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$carb))`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data set is called `df`, you could do the following with the **tidyverse** packages:

```
library(tidyverse)

result <- df %>% 
  count(Predict_DAS.Student_Ethnicity, Predict_DAS.PreDAS_Ethnicity) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Predict_DAS.PreDAS_Ethnicity, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

  Predict_DAS.Student_Ethnicity   `Black/African…` `No Selection` `White/Caucasi…` Asian Other
  <chr>                                      <int>          <int>            <int> <int> <int>
1 American Indian or Alaskan Nat…                1              3                2     0     0
2 Asian                                          0              2                1     1     1
3 Black/African American                        19             11                2     1     0
4 Hispanic/Latinx                                1              8                0     0     0
5 Multiple                                       1              4                2     0     1
6 Native Hawaiian or Pacific Isl…                0              2                1     1     0
7 No Selection                                   2              4                0     0     1
8 Other                                          1              4                0     1     3
9 White/Caucasian                                3             12               32     2     1
# … with 2 more variables: `Hispanic/Latinx` <int>, Multiple <int>
```